# What is the correct way for loading application.properties in multiple classes?

Tags: java, spring, properties

Is there a better way than calling loadProperties() in every class it's needed?

```
public void loadProperties() {
    InputStream inputStream;
    prop = new Properties();
    String propFileName = "application.properties";

    inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

    if (inputStream != null) {
        try {
            prop.load(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error: ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I know Spring provides this functionality with the @Value annotation, but this only works if you mark the class as an @Service. Although this does not seem to be the *right* way

Comment: Why would you need to load it manually? Also it works for any spring bean to only `@Service` annotated beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring in the way：The first method
   There is also a way that is annotated in the java code to use the @Value annotation to load the value of the configuration file，Marked on the class @Component, @Service, @Controller, @Repository
  for example:

```
   @Component("fileUpload") 
public class FileUploadUtil implements FileUpload { 

 private String filePath; 
 @Value("#{prop.filePath}") 
 public void setFilePath(String filePath) { 
  System.out.println(filePath); 
  this.filePath = filePath; 
 }
```

bean.xml

```
<bean id="prop" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"> 
 <property name="locations">
  <array> 
   <value>classpath:public.properties</value> 
  </array> 
 </property> 
</bean>
```

Second method:Use a configuration file
   for example:

```
   <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:conn.properties"/>
 <bean id="dataSource" class="${dataSource}"> 
 <property name="driverClass" value="${driverClass}" /> 
 <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbcUrl}" /> 
 <property name="user" value="${user}" /> 
 <property name="password" value="${password}" /> 
 </bean>
```

I think these two methods are the simplest. The second method is not flexible.
  Java in the use of Properties will allow code redundancy。But you can also extract this method。

Answer (score 0):

The best way is indeed using @Value annotation.

Note that it works with any Spring managed bean like
@Component, @Service, @Controller, @Repository

Answer (score 0):

In case of classes that are not services you can use prototype scoped beans and instantiate them using the application context inside your function.

```
applicationContext.getBean("aScopedBean");
```

They are like your usual non-singleton java object with the beans you need from your spring context.

If you want to have your properties in a map you can inject the Environments.

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
...
env.getProperty("a_property");
```

If you want to avoid the @Autowire generally then you have to implement an  Utility function or class.